# C - Passing an int value from a char string

Tags: c, string, char, segmentation-fault, int

I have the following function, and I want to test if the two strings are anagrams. One way I thought about doing it would be to sum the values of each of the characters in the strings and then compare their values.

However, I am getting a segmentation fault in both the for loops when I try to run my program. I am not understanding this correctly, is there anything I am doing incorrectly in my code?

```
int anagram(char *a, char *b)
{
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    char *p, *q;

    for (p=a; p != '\0'; p++) {
        sum1 += *p - 'a';
    }

    for (q=b; q != '\0'; q++) {
        sum2 += *q - 'a';
    }

    if ( sum1 == sum2 )
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should be `*p != '\0'` and `*q != '\0'`. Since `p` and `q` are not NULL pointers, your loops are infinite loops.

Comment: @Barmar I mean that If i enter hello for string a and loleh for string b I would return a 1

Comment: And how does adding up the characters tell you if they're anagrams? You'll get the same sums for `"abc"` and `"bc"`.

Comment: @Barmar, you confused anagram with palindrome. However the approach of sum would not work. "ad" and "bc" will give the same sum

Comment: Make copies of the strings, sort them, and then see if they're equal.

Comment: Or use a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). In other words, create a histogram of the letters in each word, and then verify that the histograms are the same.

Comment: Don't sum, *count* the occurrences of the characters and compare the counts. A different method would be to associate a prime number with each character, and *multiply* them together. For this, though, using C built-in data types certainly won't be large enough.

Comment: What does comparing sums do? If unsigned sums differ, string are **not** anagrams.  If the sums match, strings **might** be anagrams.  Not a complete test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `for` loops you must check

`*p != '\0'`

`*q != '\0'`

This is the cause of the seg-fault.

---

Furthermore, even fixed, that code will give you false positives:

"bc" anagram of "ad"

I suggest you a different approach:

make two arrays of `int`s sized 256, zero initialized.

Let every item of each array keep the count of every letter (char) of each string.

Finally compare if the two arrays are the same.

I leave the task of writig the code to you.

Comment: @chqrlie His whole idea of using sums to test for anagrams is wrong, but that's not what the question asked about.

Comment: His question is quite confusing... But I prefer answers to address most if not all issues.

Answer (score 1):

"p !=0" should be "*p != 0", as it is now you are waiting for the pointer to become null.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution for your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *str1, const void *str2) {
    return (*((char*)str1) - *((char*)str2));    
}

bool areAnagram(char *str1, char *str2) {
    int n1 = strlen(str1);
    int n2 = strlen(str2);

    if (n1 != n2)
      return false;

    qsort(str1, n1, 1, &cmp);
    qsort(str2, n2, 1, &cmp);

    for (int i = 0; i < n1;  i++)
       if (str1[i] != str2[i])
         return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "test";
    char str2[] = "tset";
    if (areAnagram(str1, str2))
      printf("The two strings are anagram of each other");
    else
      printf("The two strings are not anagram of each other");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux: Thanx, I didn't run it. Just wrote it from memory. Exchanged the line with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Since we're already giving answers about better approaches, here's mine:

Get a list of (preferably small) prime numbers. You need one for every possible character of your input strings, thus when you want to check strings containing only digits 0 to 9 you need 10 prime numbers. Let's take these:

```
static unsigned const primes[10] = {
  2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
```

Now, since each number has exactly one prime factorisation, and because of multiplication being commutative, you can just build the product of the prime numbers for each character of your string. If they're identical, then for each character holds that it has been the same number of times in both strings. Thus, both strings are anagrams of each other.

```
unsigned long prime_product(char const * str) {
  assert(str != NULL);
  unsigned long product = 1;
  for (; *str != '\0'; ++str) {
    assert(*str >= '0');
    assert(*str <= '9');
    product *= primes[*str - '0'];
  }
  return product;
}

char is_anagram(char const * one, char const * two) {
  return prime_product(one) == prime_product(two);
}
```

This should even work to some extend when the product overflows, though then false positives are possible (though their likelihood can be greatly reduced when also comparing the length of the two strings).

As can be seen this version has `O(n)` time and constant space complexity.

Comment: Not bad, but will need `uint128_t` to handle 26 different symbols.